# Cannot locate text inside #shadow-root (user-agent)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, shadow-dom, dropdownbox

- [Image of HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OYte.png)
- [Image of the Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtXBh.png)

I'm using Selenium - Java with testNG for automating webpage.

As you can see in the image of the website, there is a 'Timezone' dropdown menu with 'Please Select' as the default value. I want to locate the 'Please Select' text which is present in the `<div> aria-hidden = "true" Please Select</div>` line under `#shadow-root (user-agent)`.

If I try to locate the text - 'Please Select' ,  I was unsuccessful.

1. Getting `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchShadowRootException: no such shadow root` exception when I tried the below method.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("timezone"));
        WebElement shadowRoot1 = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", element);
        String text = shadowRoot1.findElement(By.cssSelector("div")).getText();
        System.out.println(text);
```

2. Also tried to locate the element using `getShadowRoot()` method but the same exception occurs again.

Also attaching the [debugging screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jV2NM.png)  for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any `#shadow-root` in the html source code.

Extracting desired text using `element.getText()` is working just fine.

**Code example:**

```
package tests;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

import selenium.ChromeDriverSetup;

public class DhanushS extends ChromeDriverSetup {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        WebDriver driver = startChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://dash.bling-center.com/platform/home.html");
        driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("testuser2704@mailinator.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("testuser2704");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/button/p")).click();
        
        driver.findElement(By.id("phone-tab")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("phonenumber_1")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("area_code")).sendKeys("+420");        
        driver.findElement(By.id("phonenumber_continue")).click();
        
        WebElement setBusinessHours = driver.findElement(By.id("setBusinessHours"));
        WebElement businesshoursCheck = setBusinessHours.findElement(By.tagName("input"));
        
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", businesshoursCheck);

        WebElement timezone = driver.findElement(By.id("timezone"));
        
        String tzText = timezone.getText();
        System.out.println("All options text:" + System.lineSeparator() + tzText);
        
        Select select = new Select(timezone);       
        String selectedTzText = select.getFirstSelectedOption().getText();
        System.out.println("Selected option text:" + System.lineSeparator() + selectedTzText);

        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
Starting ChromeDriver 111.0.5563.64 (c710e93d5b63b7095afe8c2c17df34408078439d-refs/branch-heads/5563@{#995}) on port 23727
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
[1682600077.367][WARNING]: This version of ChromeDriver has not been tested with Chrome version 112.
Dub 27, 2023 2:54:37 ODP. org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
All options text:
                          Please Select
                          US/Hawaii
                          America/Los Angeles
                          America/Vancouver
                          Canada/Pacific
                          America/Chicago
                          Canada/Central
                          America/New York
                          America/Montreal
                          America/Toronto
                          Canada/Eastern
                          America/Phoenix
                        
Selected option text:
Please Select
```